# convergence of $\max(\;f(\frac{k}{n})\;;0\le k\le n)$ where $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. I would like to prove that $$u_n:=\max\bigl(\;f(\frac{k}{n})\;;0\le k\le n\bigr)$$ converges.

My idea was to use Heine's theorem to prove that $(u_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence of $\mathbb{R}$, hence converges.

I introduce the subdivision $(a_{i,k})_{0\le i\le k/n}$ of any interval $[0,\frac{k}{n}]$ for $k=0,\ldots,n$ such that $\delta(a_{i,k})<\eta$ where $\eta$ is the real $>0$ which appears in the definition of uniformly convergent.

If I am correct we get that $$\vert f(\frac{k}{m+n})-f(\frac{k}{n})\vert\le \varepsilon$$ because $\vert\frac{k}{m+n}-\frac{k}{n}\vert\le\delta(a_{i,k)}<\eta.$

Not sure how to get the result

Comment: It seems like it will be easier to consider that you really "know" what $u_n$ is converging to: it is converging to the maximum of $f$. Generally when you know what the limit is, it's easier to use that to prove convergence rather than passing through the Cauchy criterion.

Comment: As for how to do that, let $\varepsilon>0$, introduce $\delta(\varepsilon)$ from uniform continuity, look at $n>1/\delta(\varepsilon)$ and try to conclude that $u_n$ is within $\varepsilon$ of the maximum of $f$. This works fine on a compact interval, but it is still an interesting exercise to think about how to avoid using uniform continuity. This alternate case would require you to allow $u_n \to +\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $u_n = f(k_n/n)$ for some $0 \le k_n \le n$. Now $k_n/n$ is bounded. Hence for any subsequence we have a subsequence which is convergent. Say $k_{n_m}/n_m \rightarrow x$. Then $u_n \rightarrow f(x)$.

Claim: $f(x) = \max_{y \in [0,1]} f(y)$, i.e. the limes is always the same. (This already implies the convergence of the sequence. Why?)

First of all: $f(x) \le \max_{y \in [0,1]} f(y)$ On the other, because of continuity, there is $z \in [0,1]$ with $$f(z) = \max_{y \in [0,1]} f(y).$$
Since the set $\{k/n_m : 0 \le k \le n_m, m\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$, there exists a sequence $(k_i/n_{m_i})_i$ with $f(k_i/n_{m_i}) \rightarrow f(z)$. Hence $f(k_i/n_{m_i}) \le u_{n_{m_i}}$ and $f(z) \le f(x)$.

Comment: So you are using that a sequence converges if and only if for any subsequence we have a subsequence which is convergent, right ? But we need that the limit does not depend of the "subsequence", which is the last part of your proof. thanks

Comment: Yes, convergence towards $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to the statement that every subsequence has a subsequence which converges to $x$. Important part: The limes is independent of the subsequence. Proof: $\Rightarrow$ is trivial. $\Leftarrow$: Assume $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not convergent, then there exists $\varepsilon >0$ such that $|x_n -x | > \varepsilon$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Take this subsequence. It doesn't convergence to $x$. Contradiction!